# Não consigo aplicar Encoder no texto para aparecer corretamente "ç, acentos, outros caracteres especiais"

Tags: c#, .net, string, codificação-de-caracteres

Olá,

Preciso coletar uma informações da estação, e estou conseguindo. Porém no texto recebido não consigo aplicar um Encoder para aparecer corretamente os caracteres especiais:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei usar o "ISO-8859-1", e outras formas de encode também

```
string blah = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(suaString));
```

ou

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sOutput);
sOutput = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
var teste = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Comment: Já tentou com o `Encoding.GetEncoding(850)`?

Comment: não, vou tentar!

Comment: @jbueno não deu certo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para contornar a dificuldade eu peguei os caracteres que estava vindo e fiz replace pelos caracteres equivalentes :

```
sOutput = sOutput.Replace('?', 'ç').Replace('Æ', 'ã').Replace('¢', 'ó').Replace('¡', 'í').Replace("Portuguçs","Português");
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiz uma aplicação aqui e rodei em uma maquina Windows 10 em português e uma outro com windows 10 em Inglês, e  nas duas maquinas eu obtive o mesmo resultado.

Quando eu fiz apenas a linha abaixo:

```
string sOutput = CurrentProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

a codificação estava correta, porém quando eu executei

```
Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("us-ascii");
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(sOutput);
byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, utfBytes);
sOutput = iso.GetString(isoBytes);
```

O mesmo problema que você está tendo aconteceu.

Ou seja, não vejo a necessidade de você fazer as conversões.

Comment: Tiago S Não deu certo, veja:   Nome do host:                              CPU-434A
Nome do sistema operacional:               Microsoft Windows 7 Professional 
VersÆo do sistema operacional:             6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 compila‡Æo 7601
Fabricante do sistema operacional:         Microsoft Corporation
Configura‡Æo do SO:                        Esta‡Æo de trabalho membro

Comment: Esta linha `string sOutput = CurrentProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();` retornou isso?

Comment: Sim, retornou da forma que esta ali.